# How to track down a ReferenceError in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn

I have hit a problem that seems like it might be some sort of bug in the Nashorn engine, but I can't figure out a good way to distill a test case that will demonstrate it.

I have a block of code (that used to work!) which looks roughly like this:

```
'use strict';
function Dummy() {
  this.val = 'I am fubar';
  this.aContainer = [];
}
Dummy.prototype.toString = function() { return JSON.stringify(this);};

let obj = {};
obj.aMethod = function(arg) {
  let fubar = new Dummy();
  print('Okay so far');

  fubar.aContainer.push({"some":"thing"});
  print('Still okay');
  fubar.aContainer.push({"==": [{"var": "something_else"}, fubar.val]});

  return fubar;
};

print(obj.aMethod(null));
```

Unfortunately, running this example with `jss --language=es6 -strict` doesn't crash.  In my real code though, I get the following:

`jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: ReferenceError: "fubar" is not defined`

If I change the code as follows, it runs fine:

```
'use strict';
function Dummy() {
  this.val = 'I am fubar';
  this.aContainer = [];
}
Dummy.prototype.toString = function() { return JSON.stringify(this);};

let obj = {};
obj.aMethod = function(arg) {
  let fubar = new Dummy();
  print('Okay so far');

  fubar.aContainer.push({"some":"thing"});
  print('Still okay');
  let x = fubar.val;
  fubar.aContainer.push({"==": [{"var": "something_else"}, x]});

  return fubar;
};

print(obj.aMethod(null));
```

Is there anything I can do to try to instrument the real code further or otherwise track this issue down?  The odd thing is the error happens very early in execution.  If I put a print() call anywhere in the method, the print is never reached.  The last line of my code in the callstack is actually the line that calls the method.

I did just pick up a new version of Java via auto-update, but I need to see if this code is running under it or not.  My current version from the console is:

```
➜  ~ java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I've run your first code with java version "1.8.0_121" without any problem. This is the output: `{"val":"I am fubar","aContainer":[{"some":"thing"},{"==":[{"var":"something_else"},"I am fubar"]}]}`. How do you get the engine from the factory? This is how I get it:    `NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory(); ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine(new String[] { "--language=es6" });`

Comment: Yes, thank you for trying that.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to create a simple example case that exhibits the problem.  This leads me to believe that something about the memory usage in my application is causing that variable to be collected or lifted improperly when a certain method call or property set is made.  Copying the variable to a new instance seems to dodge the improper handling, but I am stuck trying to figure out a way that I could share relevant information with the Nashorn team to help them track it down.

Comment: Did you try to enable tracing? See this https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-callsite_tracing

Comment: I've just found this http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/nashorn/file/tip/docs/DEVELOPER_README. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Awesome, I will try to instrument my code with some of these options.  I would be happy to mark this information as an answer to my question if you want to add it.

Comment: Ok I'll add it as an answer but mark it as correct only if it really helps you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full summary of all you can do to trace Nashorn is contained in this document:

[jdk8u-dev/nashorn/file/tip/docs/DEVELOPER_README](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/nashorn/file/tip/docs/DEVELOPER_README)

It describes system properties that are used for internal debugging and instrumentation purposes, along with the system loggers, which are used for the same thing.